# spring-boot-maven-plugin: where it is loaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to implement step by step all instructions that are defined here:

[Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

and I have got a question regarding section: **11.4 Running the example**

They wrote:

> At this point our application should work. Since we have used the
> spring-boot-starter-parent POM we have a useful run goal that we can
> use to start the application. Type mvn spring-boot:run from the root
> project directory to start the application

I did not add *spring-boot-maven-plugin* directly to my *pom.xml*

I see that in *spring-boot-starter-parent* module *spring-boot-maven-plugin* are defined in *pom.xml* only in **< pluginManagement>** section, it means that in parent module only default configuration for plugin described.

And now I can't understand **how and where** the plugin is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html), Maven is just a collection of plugins that do everything your project needs to be correctly compiled.

But note that you don't explicitly declare a vast majority of them. For example, the Clean plugin (which removes the target directory) is not declared in your pom, but if you type `mvn clean` the plugin is loaded and executed.

It's Maven itself that loads the plugin and it's the same with `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, as long as you have a configuration for this plugin, which is the case as you declare the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your parent.

To further understand this, you can try the build configuration described in **13.2.2 Using Spring Boot without the Parent POM** of [this Spring documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html)

You'll see that if you don't explicitely include the spring boot plugin, you'll get an error *"No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project"*